# Backbone - user case

Tags: backbone.js

Say a user is going down a page and checking off and selecting items.
I have a Backbone model object, and each time the user selects something I want to update the object.

I have this in a separate JavaScript file that I source in my HTML:

```
var app = {}; 
var newLineup = null;

var team = document.getElementsByName('team');

app.Lineup = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        team: team,
        completed: false
    },
    idAttribute: "ID",
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('Book has been intialized');
        this.on("invalid", function (model, error) {
            console.log("Houston, we have a problem: " + error)
        });
    },
    constructor: function (attributes, options) {
        console.log('document',document);
        console.log('Book\'s constructor had been called');
        Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    validate: function (attr) {
        if (attr.ID <= 0) {
            return "Invalid value for ID supplied."
        }
    },
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3000/api/lineups'
});

function createNewLineupInDatabase(){
    newLineup = new app.Lineup({team: team, completed: false}); 

    newLineup.save({}, {
        success: function (model, respose, options) {

        },
        error: function (model, xhr, options) {

        }
    });
}
```

When the user first accesses the page, I will create a new lineup object by calling the above function. But how do I update that object as the user interacts with the page? Is there a better way to do this other than putting the Backbone model object at the top of my JavaScript file?

Answer (score 2):

The Backbone pattern was designed to answer your question. As other respondents said, wire up a View, which takes your model as a parameter and lets you bind DOM events to the model.

That said, you don't *have* to use the rest of the framework. I guess you can use all the functionality Backbone provides models by handling the model yourself.

You need to worry about a couple of things.

1. Give you model a little encapsulation.
2. Set up a listener (or listeners) for your `checkbox` items.

### Scope the model to your app

Backbone provides neat encapsulation for your model inside a View, but if you can live with it, just use your `app` variable which is within scope of the JavaScript file you posted.

When you're ready to instantiate your model, make it a property of `app`:

```
app.newLineup = new app.Lineup({team: team, completed: false});
```

It may look weird to have the instance and the constructor in the same object, but there aren't other options until you pull out the rest of Backbone.

### The listener

So you have N number of checkboxes you care about. Say you give them a class, say, `.options`. Your listener will look like

```
$( ".options" ).change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff with your model
        //You can access it from app.newLineup 
    } else {

    }
});
```

Voila! Now your page is ready to talk to your model.

Comment: But it's not the answer you're looking for... Give me some more background and I can expand on the Answer

Answer (score 1):

If there is frontend ui / any user interaction within your code it is extremely useful to create a backbone view which makes use of an events object where you can set up your event handler.

You can also link a view to a model to allow your model / your object to be updated without scope issues.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you don't want to store your object within your model's defaults?